# how to link a keyboard key with a button [MAUI]

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am making a calculator that works on windows and android. What I want to do is when we are on a computer as soon as you press a key on the keyboard, it presses the button in the application (like in the windows calculator). Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

i test unsing KeyRoutedEventArgs but it dosent existe

```
public void MyKeyDownEventHandler(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == 70)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("'F' key pressed");
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to press a specific key on the keyboard to trigger a button, or press  any key on the keyboard to trigger a button in the application?

Comment: press a specific key on the keyboard to trigger a button

Comment: You can try to achieve this with CustomRenderer ,check this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3b00507-0765-49c8-bdb8-e1477f494465/how-to-make-a-accelerator-key-for-xamarinforms-button-?forum=xamarinforms#latest) .